# Lights flicker in whole house

Tags: electrical

Just moved into a house and have noticed that the lights flicker. Some are LEDS but others are incandescent bulbs - doesn’t seem to matter.
The flickering is a low level “tremor”. Electricians are stumped. Voltage seems steady from the breaker. Power company replaced the transformer and lines to my house, and yet lights still flicker.
I had receptacles all rewired because they were ungrounded, yet that seems unrelated.
Sometimes the lights surge and get brighter, but that is a rarer occurrence compared with the flickering.
I have systematically turned off circuits that I thought may be problematic, and yet that doesn’t do anything. So, I can’t tell whether this is a problem within the house or outside/utility side.
I have had multiple electricians inspect breaker connections and all tell me they are tight with no evidence of damage. Bus bars(?) look fine without any evidence of damage. I’m at a complete loss here.

Considering what has been inspected and also done by the utility, what other possibilities could there be? Any help is much appreciated - thank you.

Comment: You turned off circuits to test that as a fix, fine. But are all of the flickering lights on a single circuit? Just two circuits? Do lamps plugged into additional circuits flicker?

Comment: I am assuming that you actually turned off the breakers. With all breakers off but the lights  do they still flicker

Comment: Does the flickering happen when something else happens?  People walking around, somethings turns on?  Is it all the time the lights are on, or just certain times?  The lights getting brighter usually only happens with an increase in power/voltage.  This can be caused by a loose neutral or power surges on the line.

Comment: @popham: The flickering lights are on multiple different circuits. It is most often consistently on two separate circuits. Sometimes, additional areas of the house on totally separate circuits also exhibit flickering. Yes, some lamps plugged into wall receptacles that are additional circuits also flicker.

Comment: @Rohit Gupta: I systematically turned off one breaker at a time on areas I theorized may be causing this problem e.g. HVAC, AC, other major appliances, etc. Turning these off did not have an impact on the flickering.

Comment: @crip659: The flickering is not affected by walking around, jumping on the floor, etc. The lights flicker 100% of the time in two areas on separate circuits, and maybe 50% of the time more systemically throughout the house — bathrooms, basement. I can’t detect any times of the day when the flickering is worse. I did once observe that I was able to make the flickering worse in the kitchen by using my espresso machine. In other words, the kitchen ceiling lights were already flickering without any appliances being used. Then, using the coffee machine, made the flickering appreciably worse.

Comment: Usually I look for a single point of failure. What's the likelihood that two problems emerge simultaneously? In your case, though, the previous owners may have neglected things as diffuse problems (or diffuse instances of the same problem pattern) failed sequentially to reach the system's current state. Do you have backstab light switches? Do you have arc fault breakers on the flickering circuits? If not, then can you install an arc fault breaker on a flickering circuit to see if it trips periodically?

Comment: Just LEDs might be a problem with them, but the other light types point to a problem with the wires/circuits.  One circuit, it would be easy to say a loose connection, two circuits a bit harder.  More than two, the possibility of outside problems and/or a complete rewire of the house goes up.  You don't mention that the professionals said anything should be changed, so the panel/wires/cables look to be good condition(no known bad panels, knob and tube wires).

Comment: No question that the previous homeowner neglected electrical. Old fixtures, different kinds of bulbs inside fixtures, broken switches, and most receptacles were ungrounded. No receptacles are backstabbed nor switches now. Also, no arc fault circuit breakers— just the standard ones and GFCI on a few. So. If I installed an arc fault breaker on a circuit, what exactly would that be testing— if it trips? If not?

Comment: It’s the whole house that flickers, just more noticeable in certain areas. Panel is Eaton 200 amp, not very old. Electricians tell me the panel looks fine, screws tight, no burns or evidence of problems from there. Nobody is confident about the source. The power CO did replace the transformer, lines to house, and obviously made new connections. However, I am thinking could it be possible that the power meter itself could be bad? In other words, the Power CO made new connections within the meter, but could the meter be faulty? I’m not sure what the meter actually does or how it works.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc-fault_circuit_interrupter. Ideally I would want a logger to record the current history of a circuit for diagnostic purposes. Since that sounds out of bounds, I figure a decent substitute is an AFCI breaker, where it would tell you if the flickering lights are being caused by arcing conditions. I don't have high confidence that tripping establishes arcing as the exact cause, where other conditions can trip them also, but if they didn't trip at all, then that sounds like good evidence that the problem is not arcing.

Comment: Why don't you disconnect one of the flickering circuits, disconnect a light that flickers, and install the light directly to the flickering circuit's breaker with new wire? Test if removing the house wiring from the circuit cures the flickering?

Comment: ThI se are very fine ideas— thank you. While the flickering happens most noticeably in a couple of areas of the house, it really is a whole-house systemic problem, as I have observed it pretty much everywhere at different times. I’m not sure if that is a meaningful detail at this point. The AFCI circuit sounds like an empirical test so far as arching somewhere within the nest of electrically wiring within the house. A data logger would be a very powerful tool, it seems. (cont.)

Comment: I think I understand, please allow me to phrase in my own words for comprehension purposes: What you’re saying is, if the AFCI doesn’t trip, that would suggest the flickering is not due to arching, or poor/damaged connections within the house, and so the arching explanation can be somewhat confidently eliminated? Then, connecting a bulb directly to a circuit bypassing house wiring, essentially tests the basic location of the issue— e.g., within house, or outside house, correct? Your responses are so very appreciated, as my family is rather upset. A very warm thank you.